# Get available physical drives on local machine

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am trying to get all the physical drives available on local machine. 
I tried to use `GetLogicalDrives()` but when i'm using this function it gets me also drives that physically not available on the machine, for example floppy drive A. 
Here is my code:

```
void FindDrives()
{
    DWORD drives = GetLogicalDrives();
     for (int i=0; i<26; i++)
     {
        if( ( drives & ( 1 << i ) ) )
        {
           wchar_t driveName[] = { L'A' + i, L':', L'\\', L'\0'};
           std::wcout << driveName << std::endl;
        }
     }
}
```

How can I get only physically available drives?

Comment: Please narrow down what you expect to be a "physical drive".

Comment: If you are for the "real" physical drives (not for things like A:, B:, C:, ...) this is not as simple a issueing one API call. A possible solution could be found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264203

Comment: @alk When I'm using code that mentioned in question I get a:\ c:\ d:\ and e:\, but a:\ are no floppy disk on my machine. I would get only c:\ d:\ and e:\

Comment: Such are not necessarily physical drives. Go for Joze's hint using `GetDriveType()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: `GetLogicalDrives()` will not return an `A:` drive if there is no `A:` drive installed. If you want to check if a removable drive has media in it, you have to query the drive separately. `GetDriveType()` may tell you whether a drive supports removable media or not, but it will not tell you if there is actual media in the drive. For that, you have to actually ask the drive directly, such as with `DeviceIoControl()`, or at least `GetVolumeInformation()` or `GetDiskFreeSpace/Ex()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)

```
wmic diskdrive list
```

for less info

```
wmic diskdrive list brief
```

Alternatively in c use GetLogicalDrives() first to get all of the drives mapped in the system, and then GetDriveType() to find out which sort of drive each one is. Then sort it out as you want to.